# Resolve "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" issue with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a **Chrome Extension** that pre-populates fields then submits the form on an external website when I visit it.

It works perfectly when the data is hard-coded into my `script.js` file.
However, I'd like to grab the username from an element in my Intranet home page & use this in the script instead of hard coding it.

I have made a simple `script.js` to test this works:

**script.js:**

```
$.get('https://intranet/index.php', function(data){ 
    alert('test');
});
```

When I try to use this in my Extension and reload the page, I get the error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://intranet/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://eecikfibchjhmochelhmhlimbcjglldf' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

---

When this same code is run at https://intranet/test.html it works perfectly.

**test.html:**

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('https://intranet/index.php', function(data){ 
    $(document.body).load('https://intranet/ #username');
});
</script>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo '<div id="username">username</div>';
?>
```

I have read that some use `JSONP` to resolve this issue. Does anyone have experience of this?

Can anyone provide help/advice on this issue?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: "The response had HTTP status code 401." indicates it's an authentication issue in getting the resource, so the header would not be present as it would be sent once the script is processed, which the web server does not allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two issues here at once.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Doesn't look like you thoroughly searched for solutions, since it's a common problem. Anyway, there are 2 ways to solve this:

1. On the extension side. If you have host permissions, you can do cross-origin requests regardless of CORS headers. (note: *"When this same code is run at https://intranet/test.html it works perfectly"* highlights that the issue is **cross**-origin but works on the same site).

   There's a whole extension documentation article on this: [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), but an ultra-short version: you need to add permissions for the site in the manifest:

   ```
   "permissions": [
     "https://intranet/*"
   ],
   ```
2. On the server side, by adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. Note that this solution opens a certain attack surface (not only your extension can do requests now), so approach 1 is preferable.

That said: you tried to implement approach 2, and it didn't work. Why? Because there is a second problem:

> The response had HTTP status code 401

HTTP 401 is "Unauthorized". Your requests lack the authorization necessary - which you don't see when using the intranet site itself, since the browser already have those credentials cached.

But they won't be applied to cross-origin requests, so you get a 401 error page instead of the intended page - that doesn't contain your header.

You need to provide authorization along with the request. jQuery allows that:

```
$.get(
  {
    url: 'https://intranet/index.php',
    username: '...',
    password: '...'
  }, function(data){ 
    alert('test');
  }
);
```

I think it should be obvious that this shouldn't be hardcoded in the extension.

Comment: First - **many thanks** for such a _detailed_ response : )
I have added the `permissions` portion and have also updated the `script.js` to include your jQuery sample. The code works locally with/without username & password but **fails in the Extension** with this error message: `jquery-2.0.3.js:7845 GET https://www.third-party-url.here/[object%20Object] 403 (Forbidden)`. That line in my jQuery refers to `xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );`.

Comment: Well, again, you're missing some authorization required, most likely - be it a cookie, an API key in the request or something similar. This is outside the scope of the question and really depends on the third party in question.

Comment: @Xan Hello. I have set the permission in `manifest.json` yet I am facing the same error. No authorization is required in the api. A sample api url: http://loklak.org/api/search.json?q=from%3Anoone . Could you share your thought on this issue?